# CSRF protection with Session Id

Tags: authentication, javascript, xss, cookies, csrf

To protect against CSRF, couldn't my page javascript just dynamically insert the session id from the cookie into the body of each HTTP request right before it's sent?

The server would then just validate that (value received from cookie) == (value from request body)...

Comment: **Known fact:** Your website has be able to work *without* JavaScript.

Comment: **So what?** I'll just make Javascript mandatory

Comment: Well whatever, this will not protect you from CSRF IMO. CSRF is about an attacker sending a link to a user tricking him to do something, so I don't see how this will stop it ?

Comment: Because the attacker can't read my session id cookie value due to same-origin-policy, and won't likely guess it.

Comment: Then I think you're talking about session-hijacking ...

Comment: No it's CSRF protection since you're also validating that the cookie value is the same as the other value added to the request via the page's javascript. If it's not the same you've detected CSRF otherwise you are ok.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Are you sure about that? http://dsigninspire.com/2010/05/9-websites-that-are-built-entirely-using-javascript/

Comment: @D3C4FF Serious websites should work without JS, although the probability to encounter IE 3 or Opera 2 is almost 0, what if the user has JS disabled ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV If a user running IE 3 hits any site i've created they'll promptly be told to go back to sleep.

Comment: @D3C4FF I would do it too, actually I even banned IE on one internal website :p

Comment: @ManRow, SOP will not guarantee protection. Perhaps in combination with a properly configured CSP (Content Security Policy) you may be able to avoid XSS and CSRF in the scenario you describe above.

Comment: @D3C4FF: Doesn't matter. If your _server_ accepts POST/GET requests without validating the request, it is vulnerable to CSRF. Servers don't care about javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Edit: what I propose below is apparently known as the [double-submit cookie scheme](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie). And, contrary to the original question, it is a separate nonce altogether as well (or even a simple hash of the session id)...

---

Looks like the simple solution (i.e., CSRF protection but with all-cacheable web resources) is to just add a separate cookie containing the anti-CSRF token but accessible to page javascript. And add this to all requests from the page (e.g., just before they're sent).

In other words, when the client logs in, I'll actually set *two* cookies (one HttpOnly sessionid and one nonp-HttpOnly anti-CSRF token, accessed by page scripts). So, the server will store (along with a client sessionid) their anti-CSRF token value and validate that it's the same value as the one originally set via the second cookie. If validation fails, you have a potential CSRF.

This approach is also mentioned in some other places on the web...

Comment: And what would stop the 2nd cookie from being submitted by a CSRF attack, same as the session id cookie...?

Comment: Because the CSRF cookie is submitted **twice**: (#1) once as a regular cookie (just a regular cookie w/o CSRF protection), but ALSO (#2) as a property dynamically added  (at the same time) via the page's javascript into the body of every request from that page. The server will validate that the anti-CSRF token value passed via mechanism #1 (standard cookie mechanism) is the *same* as the one sent (at the same time) via mechanism #2 (the value of which only your page's javascript can access); if it's not the same or missing, the server will suspect CSRF.

Comment: Of course, the anti-CSRF cookie value will just be overwritten/reset every time the user gets a new sessionid...

Comment: ah, I see - that was not clear from your answer. However, while this scheme could work fine (I dont see any issues with it offhand), it needlessly over-complicates things. Why try to build this (and you will probably get some parts wrong, like the cryptographic bits), when you have a perfectly fine mechanism built in to almost any framework or platform you're using?

Comment: **Cache-ability**: my *entire site* is now cache-able, since the server doesn't need to cook this token into the returned HTML each time. I can now just use all static HTML & JS files...

Comment: @AviD Just realized that what you mentioned that my answer did not explicitly specify to inject the anti-CSRF token right before a request is sent out. So I've updated my answer for clarity (made sure to specify this directly).

Answer (score 17):

No because you should never allow scripts to be able to access your cookies. Refer to [HTTPOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) on the OWASP website.

To prevent people from being able to steal session id's, should XSS be present, you should always set this cookie flag. Your mechanism would not work anymore as it would not be able to access the cookie.

Comment: And what if the site doesn't have any inherent XSS vulnerabilities?

Comment: @ManRow, that is a dangerous assumption to make. Making security tokens available to user-land code should  generally be avoided, unless one is completely comfortable with the consequences of doing so. It would only take one XSS vulnerability to allow an attacker to extract the token and have his way with it.

Comment: Security doesn't work with "What if this is taken out of the equation". You either go for a good approach or you just don't.

Comment: "Yeah, but what if the thief *doesn't* have a bolt-cutter"

Answer (score 17):

Quoted from [OWASP's CSRF Prevention page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookies):

> **Double Submit Cookies**
>
> Double submitting cookies is defined as sending the session ID cookie in two different ways for every form request. First as a traditional header value, and again as a hidden form value. When a user visits a site, the site should generate a (cryptographically strong) pseudorandom value and set it as a cookie on the user's machine. This is typically referred to as the session ID. The site should require every form submission to include this pseudorandom value as a hidden form value and also as a cookie value. When a POST request is sent to the site, the request should only be considered valid if the form value and the cookie value are the same. When an attacker submits a form on behalf of a user, he can only modify the values of the form. An attacker cannot read any data sent from the server or modify cookie values, per the same-origin policy. This means that while an attacker can send any value he wants with the form, the attacker will be unable to modify or read the value stored in the cookie. Since the cookie value and the form value must be the same, the attacker will be unable to successfully submit a form unless he is able to guess the session ID value.
>
> While this approach is effective in mitigating the risk of cross-site request forgery, including authenticated session identifiers in HTTP parameters may increase the overall risk of session hijacking. Architects and developers must ensure that no network appliances or custom application code or modules explicitly log or otherwise disclose HTTP POST parameters. An attacker that is able to obtain access to repositories or channels that leak HTTP POST parameters will be able to replay the tokens and perform session hijacking attacks. Note, however, that transparently logging all HTTP POST parameters is a rare occurrence across network systems and web applications as doing so will expose significant sensitive data aside from session identifiers including passwords, credit card numbers, and or social security numbers. Inclusion of the session identifier within HTML can also be leveraged by cross-site scripting attacks to bypass HTTPOnly protections. Most modern browsers prevent client-side script from accessing HTTPOnly cookies. However, this protection is lost if HTTPOnly session identifiers are placed within HTML as client-side script can easily traverse and extract the identifier from the DOM. Developers are still encouraged to implement the synchronizer token pattern as described in this article.

No real reason not to just use the built-in CSRF prevention mechanism, almost all serious frameworks have this now.

Comment: Two disadvantages with this approach:  

(1) An XSS vulnerability will now allow the attacker to also get your session id --- since it's now just another field in the DOM.  
  
(2) No cache-ability; setting this hidden field value requires the server to dynamically generate the HTML since the HttpOnly sessionid cookie values are inaccessible from javascript.      
     
While #1 still applies to my approach, at least my approach resolves #2.

Comment: Since this is the top-voted question for double submit cookies, interested users should look at this Blackhat video regarding hacks that relate to Facebook and Twitter integration http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jauXjSY-9LA

Answer (score 2):

You *could*, but it seems a bit unwieldy to me. Any CSRF-prevention mechanism works like this:

- Make the server only accept requests that satisfy some conditions
- Ensure that the conditions are something that can't be forged
- Write your HTML so that the requests it generates follow the conditions set by the server.

The tried-and-tested method is to use `<input type=hidden>` in the HTML fields that contains some anti-CSRF token. Your method works as well<sup>1</sup>, but using JS to intercept and inject POST requests sounds icky and unnecessary when the whole client-side logic can be contained in the HTML.

<sup>1 As TildalWave noted, puting sensitive data in non-`httponly` cookies and making the accessible to client side JS could be a problem if you have XSS vulnerabilities. Stick with the tried and tested method then.</sup>

Comment: Can that token just be my session id?

Comment: @ManRow: I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: @ManRow - Well, it could _potentially_ be a problem, if this value is read by a XSS, collecting end user session IDs and later used to forge requests (CSRF), or hijack user sessions. The whole point in using `httponly` in cookie headers is to signal the client (browser) not to enable client side scripts access to these cookies (usually session cookies), so they're not exposed to XSS. By adding this session ID value to a form field, you're needlessly enabling access to it. It's just safer to assume you can't trust the client, and since there's no need to do it this way, I'd suggest not to.

Comment: @TildalWave: Good point, added a note.

Comment: Another related problem - if someone manages to intercept the value by sniffing a request going past. Also, the CSRF value should be random, if possible, to also prevent replays.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: If someone is sniffing the request, they can just take the session cookie and be done with it. Why attempt CSRF when you have something better?

Comment: @Manishearth: the main purpose of CSRF is to force a user to go through a form, and thus to indirectly prevent XSS. If anything, using the SID as the hidden input makes your sesion IDs trivial to get - load up a form, write down the input[type="hidden"] value, you have the person's cookie. Another reason to stick to random values.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: How would you "load up a form"? Same origin policy makes sure that you don't GET x-site forms.

Comment: @Manishearth: good point. I fixated on a case where it was possible to break out of same-origin (which may be possible when combined with an XSS vuln).

Comment: @Manishearth: the advantage with this javascript request interception/cookie reading is cache-ability -- everything is just a static HTML/JS resource. No dynamic server page generation required...

Comment: @ManRow: Hm, true. Still, TildalWave's note about session ids still holds.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by a number people - double submit is an ok CSRF protection, provided that you use a separate nonce. Using session id is very wrong in this context, starting with the fact that sessionid has to be HTTPOnly for XSS protection.

An argument of "what if there is XSS on this page/website" is not valid - when you have XSS, CSRF is the least of your worries. The browser becomes fully remotely controllable via an injected script and CSRF is not required to force the browser to do actions on behalf of the user.

Comment: So? You could then just keep your sessionid cookie "HttpOnly" and instead just use a separate non-HttpOnly anti-CSRF token cookie for my javascript mechanism.

Comment: @ManRow: A separate cookie - yes, SessionID - no